# Azure - cannot collect custom logs using Log Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

My goal is to collect some custom logs in Azure Monitor from an external VM running on Linux. In that regard, I've installed the log analytics agent according to the MS official documentation, I ran the wizard in order to setup a custom log - that includes a sample file, a row delimiter and a location from where to collect the logs. However, I'm getting a warning message saying:

> Two successive configuration applications from OMS Settings failed – please report issue to github.com/Microsoft/PowerShell-DSC-for-Linux/issues (1)

Tried to follow the link proposed that points to Github where I wasn't able to find any solution (nor on any other link) on this and that's why I said to give it a change and ask the community in here.

Though, it is weird that the heartbeat of the machine or manual syslogs messages are being collected except for the custom logs.

Has anyone encountered this and managed to overpass it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, according to the MS answer, the above warning message is normal to be displayed. However, the reason for not collecting the logs was that in the target file that has to be processed by the `oms agent`, you need to keep appending new entries because this triggers the `oms agent` which compare and check if the file has new entries than at the last check.

Hope will help someone!